# I want to fetch live Feed's From Dex's like Uniswap sushi and pancake

Tags: 1inch-dex-aggregator, uniswapv2

I'm working on a project where we need to get prices from 3 to 4 dex on the Ethereum chain and the Solana chain. What is the best way to get a live feed from Ethereum dex? I want to fetch the live state for a pool's pair and token price even if a single transaction is done.  I want to fetch the live state that automatically updates after every transaction.

Answer (score 1):

There are data aggregators which save the state of blockchains and give the any data at current block with API, so you can simply read it. For example it's Ankr.